# z3-solver Z3.String() is not a function with angular implementation

Tags: angular, z3

I recently added the 'z3-solver' npm package to my Angular app, updated all the necessary dependencies, and conducted some tests with numeric values. Working with numeric values went smoothly; I created a variable using 'Z3.Int('x')' and performed various operations. However, when attempting to work with string data, I encountered an error in the console: "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: V0.Z3.String is not a function." The error appeared when I tried to create a string value using 'Z3.String('x')'. Does anyone have any advice on how to resolve this issue? Thank you in advance!

Angular CLI: 14.2.13

Node: 16.14.2

Package Manager: npm 8.5.0

and in *package.json:*

```
"z3-solver": "^4.12.2",
```

---

UPD:

I attempted to access strings using a **low-level API** and was able to create a string successfully. I also managed to manipulate the string using *'mk_eq'* without encountering any errors. However, when I added *'solver_assert'*, I encountered the following error: "core.mjs:6736 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): 17743752".

Here's my test example:

```
let test1 = 'olleH';
let test2 = 'Hello';
const strVar1 = Z3.mk_string(ctx, test1);
const strVar2 = Z3.mk_string(ctx, test2);
const isEquals = Z3.mk_eq(ctx, strVar1, strVar2);
const solver = Z3.mk_solver(ctx);
Z3.solver_assert(ctx, solver, isEquals);
```